# How to get CPU usage of PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I'm reading about [PostgreSQL monitoring tool](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html). I get a lot of information like database size etc. but can't find info about CPU and memory usage.
Are these informations provided by PostgreSQL server or do I have to get it by my native client application (for example, find PID of PostgreSQL and call OS API function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really a PostgreSQL monitoring tool, that's PostgreSQL's internal facilities for diagnostics, monitoring and database statistics.

For *host* monitoring you want a tool like Icinga (modernized Nagios) or Zabbix. When monitoring PostgreSQL the `check_postgres` tool is likely to be of interest.

If you're interested in getting the CPU use of a particular PostgreSQL backend process from your own custom programs, you must `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` or get the pid of the task of interest from `pg_stat_activity` then use OS-level tools and APIs to collect the desired information.

If you desired, you could write a PostgreSQL C extension function to collect the information and return it as a row or rowset over the PostgreSQL protocol, so you could `SELECT my_system_stats()`. See:

- [C-language functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html)
- [Extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html)

Essentially, you write a library in C using the PostgreSQL APIs, compile it using the `pgxs` make helper and have the server dynamically load the resulting shared object. Then you tell it what C functions are callable from SQL using `CREATE FUNCTION`. You can then call them like any other function. C extensions can call OS-level APIs or do pretty much whatever they want, though it is generally very unwise for them to create threads, write directly to PostgreSQL files/filehandles, or read/write PostgreSQL sockets.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [file_fdw extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/file-fdw.html) to get cpu load and memory stats from linux /proc filesystem. https://aaronparecki.com/2015/02/19/8/monitoring-cpu-memory-usage-from-postgres